# jsFiddle on IE10 displays in Document Mode: IE7

Tags: jsfiddle

For some reason when I go to jsFiddle, IE10 (Windows 8) goes into "Document Mode: IE7".

I have to open the tools (F12) and change it to "Standards" ... and then all is well.

Happens no matter where I go but, for an example, go to jsFiddle and navigate to this fiddle: /IdeaBlade/ExaFM/

Comment: This is not the place for JSFiddle questions. You can use our Google Group to get more information on this. http://groups.google.com/group/jsfiddle-users